# sort array by column which the values are MS. Excel's row tags

Tags: algorithm

I have this very long list of MS. Excel's row tags.

It's not ordered by column well

```php
$rowTags = [
        'A1',
        'B1',
        'C1',
        'D1',
        'EE42',
        'F1',
        'G1',
        'B2',
        'C2',
        'D2',
        'B3',
        'C3',
        'D3',
        'B4',
        'C4',
        'DD41',
        'B5',
        'C5',
        'D5',
        'B6',
        'C6',
        'D6',
        'B7',
        'C7',
        'D7',
        'B8',
        'D8',
        'B9',
        'DD93',
        'B10',
        'C10',
        'D10',
        'B11',
        'C11',
        'D11',
        'B12',
        'C12',
        'ABC122',
        'B13',
        'C13',
        'AB13',
        'B14',
        'AA52',
        'C14',
        'D14',
        'B15',
        'B16',
        'B17',
        'B18',
        'B19',
        'B20',
        'C20',
        'D20',
        'B21',
        'C21',
        'D21',
        'AA53',
        'C22',
        'D22',
        'C23',
        'D23',
        'C24',
        'D24',
        'C25',
        'C30',
        'D30',
        'C31',
        'D31',
        'C32',
        'D32',
        'C33',
        'D34',
        'DD52',
        'D36',
        'C40',
        'D40',
        'C41',
        'D41',
        'DD62',
        'C42',
        'D42',
        'C43',
        'D43',
        'C44',
        'D44',
    ];
```

done this with php:

```php
usort($rowTags, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1 <=> $item2;
});
```

to sort it from the lowest to highest value, expecting that it's ordered by column well, much like columns in Excel. But the fact is the result is still unexpected.

This is an image so you can understand my question better

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to sort column numbers and row numbers both in usort.

The below code will solve the sorting issue.

```
usort($rowTags, function ($item1, $item2) {
  $col1 = preg_replace('/[0-9]/','', $item1);
  $col2 = preg_replace('/[0-9]/','', $item2);
  $col1len = strlen($col1);
  $col2len = strlen($col2);

  // if first column's length is > second column's length, it needs to be be placed after second column
  if($col1len > $col2len) {
    return 1;
  }
  // if second column's length is > first column's length, it needs to be be placed before first column
  else if($col1len < $col2len) {
    return -1;
  }

  $colCmp = strcmp($col1, $col2);

  // if same column then sort based on row number. i.e. for B5 and B3, we need to look into row number instead
  if($colCmp === 0) {
      $row1 = intval(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/','', $item1));
      $row2 = intval(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/','', $item2));
      return $row1 > $row2;
  }


  // else sort by just normal string comaprison
  return strcmp($col1, $col2);
});
```

Output of the above code.

```
Array
(
    [0] => A1
    [1] => A100
    [2] => B1
    [3] => B2
    [4] => B3
    [5] => B4
    [6] => B5
    [7] => B6
    [8] => B7
    [9] => B8
    [10] => B9
    [11] => B10
    [12] => B11
    [13] => B12
    [14] => B13
    [15] => B14
    [16] => B15
    [17] => B16
    [18] => B17
    [19] => B18
    [20] => B19
    [21] => B20
    [22] => B21
    [23] => C1
    [24] => C2
    [25] => C3
    [26] => C4
    [27] => C5
    [28] => C6
    [29] => C7
    [30] => C10
    [31] => C11
    [32] => C12
    [33] => C13
    [34] => C14
    [35] => C20
    [36] => C21
    [37] => C22
    [38] => C23
    [39] => C24
    [40] => C25
    [41] => C30
    [42] => C31
    [43] => C32
    [44] => C33
    [45] => C40
    [46] => C41
    [47] => C42
    [48] => C43
    [49] => C44
    [50] => D1
    [51] => D2
    [52] => D3
    [53] => D5
    [54] => D6
    [55] => D7
    [56] => D8
    [57] => D10
    [58] => D11
    [59] => D14
    [60] => D20
    [61] => D21
    [62] => D22
    [63] => D23
    [64] => D24
    [65] => D30
    [66] => D31
    [67] => D32
    [68] => D34
    [69] => D36
    [70] => D40
    [71] => D41
    [72] => D42
    [73] => D43
    [74] => D44
    [75] => F1
    [76] => G1
    [77] => AA52
    [78] => AA53
    [79] => AB13
    [80] => DD41
    [81] => DD52
    [82] => DD62
    [83] => DD93
    [84] => EE42
    [85] => ABC111
    [86] => ABC122
    [87] => ABC789
    [88] => YAZ99
    [89] => ZZZZ88
)
```

Comment: You've just almost re-implemented the natural sorts in PHP.

Comment: Yep I realised that after looking at your answer

Comment: This doesn't work if one of the value of Excel's row tag is for example AA52, it will order [A1, ..., A100, AA52, ..., Z1] instead of [A1, ..., A100, ..., Z1, AA52]

Comment: @mending3 Updated answer and this should work I think.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a duplicate, but just sort naturally:

```
sort($rowTags, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if one of the value of Excel's row tag is for example AA52, it will order
`[A1, ..., A100, AA52, ..., Z1]` instead of `[A1, ..., A100, ..., Z1, AA52]`